# Extract html tags and make array from string

Tags: javascript

I am building an Angular 9 app.
In this app, the user can add HTML to a post. I want to take call instances of Blockquote and make an array of them. I also need to be able to access the title attribute and the content of the blockquote. I am trying to build an automatic tab functionality.

```
    <blockquote title="tab 1">
    Inner HTML
    </blockquote>

<blockquote title="tab 2">
    Inner HTML
    </blockquote>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the title, you could [bind to the attribute](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#binding-to-an-attribute).

The same should go for [`innerHTML` attribute binding](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-innerhtml-binding-angular).

Your example would then be

```html
<blockquote [title]="tab 2" [innerHTML]="Inner HTML">
</blockquote>
```

and controlled by a component.